# Facebook pixel getting encrypted values

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

We are tracking purchase event on our website. The problem we are facing is that order id is not being fetched properly. In tag manager and fb pixel helper extension, it is proper but on pixel dashboard, it is encrypted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the GTM Facebook pixel tag to see how OrderId is fed to it?

Comment: @Max - I have attached screenshot from pixel dashboard and google tag manager. Not getting you what you want to know?